# Can I use is null instead of isInitialized in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The following Code A is from the project [play-billing-samples](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples.git).

Can I use is null instead of `isInitialized` in Kotlin? just like Code B

**Code A**

```
lateinit private var localCacheBillingClient: LocalBillingDb

val inappSkuDetailsListLiveData: LiveData<List<AugmentedSkuDetails>> by lazy {
    if (::localCacheBillingClient.isInitialized == false) {
          localCacheBillingClient = LocalBillingDb.getInstance(application)
    }
     ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
lateinit private var localCacheBillingClient: LocalBillingDb

val inappSkuDetailsListLiveData: LiveData<List<AugmentedSkuDetails>> by lazy {
    if (localCacheBillingClient == null) {
          localCacheBillingClient = LocalBillingDb.getInstance(application)
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you'd have to change the type of the variable to `LocalBillingDb?` and get rid of the `lateinit` modifier:

```
private var localCacheBillingClient: LocalBillingDb? = null 

val inappSkuDetailsListLiveData: LiveData<List<AugmentedSkuDetails>> by lazy {
    if (localCacheBillingClient == null) {
          localCacheBillingClient = LocalBillingDb.getInstance(application)
    }
    ...
}
```